# Auto-renewing google play subscription price increase - effect on existing users?

Tags: android, google-play, subscription, in-app-subscription, auto-renewing

I have a few auto-renewing subscriptions I wish to increase the price of without affecting existing subscribers. As in, I wanted existing subscribers to continue renewing at their current price, and new subscribers to be shown the new prices.
[Example subscription I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mygr3.png)

However I'm a bit unclear on google's documentation about subscription price increases https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#price-change

It states ***Users currently subscribed to auto-renewing plans are not affected by default. Instead, a legacy price cohort is created...***
This makes me think that all is good for my case since I think these are auto-renewing subscriptions. But then it goes on to describe in detail how existing customers will be notified and will be presented with the price change, which is confusing

I started digging around and found these posts, all of which state that existing customers will be charged the new price.
[Google Play: Keep old subscription price for current subscriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70121850/google-play-keep-old-subscription-price-for-current-subscriptions)
[Change price of subscription product in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758261/change-price-of-subscription-product-in-android-app)
[Android Billing: changing the price of a subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937439/android-billing-changing-the-price-of-a-subscription)
Some therefore recommend to create a new subscription item for new users and keep the existing subscription unchanged for existing users in order to get the effect I wish above

So which is it? If I change the price of my auto-renewing subscription, will my existing customers remain on the previous price, or will they be notified and presented with the choice of ending the subscription?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you change the price, a legacy price cohort will be created and all of your existing subscribers will be placed in that bucket. They will continue to pay the old price unless you explicitly open the Play Developer Console and migrate the legacy price cohort to the new base plan price.

[This document outlines the process](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12154973?hl=en)